# How to close all active .xls files in vb6

Tags: excel, vb6

I've tried something similar to this:

```
Set kitap = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
If IsXlsOpen() = True Then
    kitap.Application.Quit
End If
```

.. but didnt work out so I neeed to find how to close all excel files before starting my program in vb6

*EDIT: Full code here:*

```
Dim i As Integer
Dim kitap As Object

Dim strcnn As String
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim Cmd As New ADODB.Command
Dim rs As New ADODB.Recordset

Private Sub Form_Load()

    strcnn = "myconn"
    cnn.Open strcnn
    Cmd.ActiveConnection = cnn

End Sub

Public Function dotdate(ByRef elem) As String
    Dim day, month, year As String

    year = Right(elem, 4)
    month = Mid(elem, Len(elem) - 5, 2)
    day = Mid(elem, 1, Len(elem) - 6)

    If Len(day) = 1 Then
        day = "0" & day
    End If

    dotdate = day & "." & month & "." & year

End Function

Public Function IsXlsOpen(wbName) As String
    Dim xl As Excel.Application

    IsXlsOpen = False
    On Error Resume Next
        Set xl = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Function    
            xl.Workbooks(wbName).Activate    
        If Err.Number = 0 Then IsXlsOpen= True    
End Function

Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim cek As String

    Set kitap = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    If IsXlsOpen("my.xls") = True Then
    kitap.Application.Quit
    End If

    kitap.Workbooks.Add

    cek = "Select * From blabla"
    rs.Open cek, cnn

    If rs.EOF = True Then
       Situation.Caption = "Situation : EOF"
    Else
       kitap.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = "ID"
       kitap.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = "Caption"
      kitap.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = "Date"
       i = i + 1
       Do While Not rs.EOF
            kitap.Cells(i + 1, 1).Value = rs.Fields("id")
            kitap.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value = rs.Fields("capt")
            kitap.Cells(i + 1, 3).Value = dotdate(rs.Fields("date"))
            rs.MoveNext
            i = i + 1              
        Loop            
        rs.Close                
    End If

    kitap.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (App.Path & "\my.xls")
    kitap.Application.Quit
    Situation.Caption = "Situation : Excel Formatted Report Ready."

    Exit Sub

err:
    rs.Close
    Situation.Caption = "Critical Error! : Connection error detected. Please reset action."
End Sub
```

Comment: There seems to be some confusion here. You are creating an instance of Excel and if another instance of Excel, or even the same one, exists, you are closing the instance you created. It would be better to check if an instance existed first. In addition, do you need to close all workbooks, or only "my.xls"? If so, why not use a different format for GetObject: `Set xl = GetObject("C:\Docs\MyXL.xls")` ↵
`xl.Close`

Comment: Also, do you mean VBA, which is native to Excel, rather than VB6?

Comment: each time im recreating a workbook and giving the same myXL.xls name while saving so thats not my case i wanna close all workbooks and if posbile save & close action what i need to do and after that i ll re create an excel workbook and fill it than ill save it. and i wanna use it for vb6 coding actually. not for excel.

Comment: I REALLY hope that you ask the user before blindly closing work they may have open.

Comment: @Deanna well actually users requested that! They dont wanna see any messages. They just want to start the program with a single button and when it finish automatically mail it to their account.. There are some situations like someguy has 15 open excel file and wanna close them all as reports and send them to a superior. Thats why i made the program this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I'm more a vbscript and vba guy, a bit more info would help:

- ie what is `IsXlsOpen`?
- what is your full kitmap code, ie have you opened and closed workbooks?
- do you have any other xl instances open (before or during your code)?.

[this link](http://www.tushar-mehta.com/excel/vba/xl_doesnt_quit/) often solves VBA issues, in fixing global references

Note that it is good practice to close/quit workbooks/instances and set them to `Nothing`, ie in Tushar's code

```
 xlWB.Close False
 xlApp.Quit
 Set xlWB = Nothing
 Set xlApp = Nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

To save and close all workbooks, [read more](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=718)

```
Option Explicit 

Sub CloseAndSaveOpenWorkbooks() 
    Dim Wkb As Workbook 

    With Application 
        .ScreenUpdating = False 

         '       Loop through the workbooks collection
        For Each Wkb In Workbooks 

            With Wkb 

                 '               if the book is read-only
                 '               don't save but close
                If Not Wkb.ReadOnly Then 

                    .Save 

                End If 

                 '               We save this workbook, but we don't close it
                 '               because we will quit Excel at the end,
                 '               Closing here leaves the app running, but no books
                If .Name <> ThisWorkbook.Name Then 

                    .Close 

                End If 

            End With 

        Next Wkb 


        .ScreenUpdating = True 
        .Quit 'Quit Excel
    End With 
End Sub
```